# How to Twitter.update in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, view, model

I have a (cut-down) Model which looks like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.update_status
        event_time = time_ago_in_words 30.minutes.from_now
        Twitter.update("Event is starting in #{event_time}")
    end
end
```

As expected, I am getting a NoMethodError exception due to trying to use a method 'time_ago_in_words' from DateHelper. How should I accomplish this, and maybe more importantly, am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: I assume `Twitter.update` posts a new tweet on someone's Twitter account?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've removed the code that's not required for the example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `extend ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` in your model
2. Change `30.mins.from_now` to `30.minutes.from_now`

I just tried it myself and have no problem doing the following:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def self.update_status
    event_time = time_ago_in_words(30.minutes.from_now)
    Twitter.update("Event is starting in #{event_time}")
  end
end
```

You have to use `extend` instead of `include`. See [this article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) for an explanation.

Comment: 1. I've tried adding this to my model, outside of methods, and inside and I get the same error. I can't understand why since other Stackoverflow questions mention the same answer. 2. I mistyped that in the example code, sorry.

Comment: I updated my answer. If this doesn't work for you, try to post more details.

Comment: I've just realised my problem, and it doesn't help that I made yet another vital mistake in my example. My update_status method is actually self.update_status, so when I run MyModel.update_status, I get the NoMethodError.

Comment: I've amended my example, sorry for that.

Comment: You have to use `extend` instead of `include`. See updated answer.

Comment: That's perfect, never used `extend` before. Thank you.